# Datatable, tengo una tabla con más campos de los que caben en él

Tags: datatable

estoy tratando de usar datatable en un CRUD con una tabla que contiene 20 campos, de los cuales solo presento 7 por pantalla por cuestiones de espacio. En mi datatable, defino los 20 campos, con display:none, para ocultar los campos que no quiero que aparezcan, pero al mismo tiempo tenerlos disponibles para editarlos. Hasta aquí todo bien, edito y se dibuja la línea modificada sin problema. 
Pero cuando doy altas, agrega el nuevo registro en el datatable con los 20 campos, ocasionando que se desfase, al parecer ignora el display:none. Cosa que no sucede con la edición. Les dejo el código que dibuja la linea editada o agregada.

```
if(opcion == 1){tablaInmuebles.row.add([id,nombre,cel1,cel2,correo,domic,tinm,toper,tmob,recs,banos,superf,constru,precio,moneda,descr,comen,uerrel,carp,stat]).draw();}
           else{tablaInmuebles.row(fila).data([id,nombre,cel1,cel2,correo,domic,tinm,toper,tmob,recs,banos,superf,constru,precio,moneda,descr,comen,uerrel,carp,stat]).draw();}
```

Y éste es el código del datable:

```
                               <td><?php echo $dat['id'] ?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $dat['nombre'] ?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $dat['cel1'] ?></td>
                               <td style='display: none;'><?php echo $dat['cel2'] ?></td>
                               <td style='display: none;'><?php echo $dat['correo'] ?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $dat['domic'] ?></td> 
                               <td><?php echo $dat['tinm'] ?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $dat['toper'] ?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $dat['tmob'] ?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $dat['recs'] ?></td>
```

Les agradezco de antemano su ayuda para destrabar este asunto.

Comment: Utilizas jQuery?

Comment: si, uso JQuery, Me sugirieron usar datatable responsive. Con ésta alternativa, declaro todos los campos. Me presenta de manera automática los primeros campos y un botón para ver el resto de los campos junto con el botón de editar. Hasta aquí todo bien. Pero al presionar el botón de editar pierdo todos los valores, ya que no está presente el tr de donde los extraigo. $(document).on("click", ".btnEditar", function(){
    fila = $(this).closest("tr");
    id = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(0)').text());
    nombre = fila.find('td:eq(1)').text();
    ...